# Conexión keycloak-MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando generar una conexión entre keycloak y una BD MySQL, este es el pool de conexión:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
           <datasources>
               <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                   <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                   <driver>h2</driver>
                   <security>
                       <user-name>sa</user-name>
                       <password>sa</password>
                   </security>
               </datasource>
             <datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true">
                 <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                 <driver>mysql</driver>
                 <pool>
                     <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                     <max-pool-size>6000</max-pool-size>
                 </pool>
                 <security>
                     <user-name>root</user-name>
                     <password>Pa$$word1</password>
                 </security>
                 <validation>
                     <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                     <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                     <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                 </validation>
             </datasource>
             <drivers>
                   <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                       <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                   </driver>
                 <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                     <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                 </driver>
             </drivers>
         </datasources>
       </subsystem>
```

Después de cierto tiempo de que el servidor esta mapeando las tablas me genera el siguiente error

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at org.jboss.threads.RejectingExecutor.execute(RejectingExecutor.java:37)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2026)
    at ...
```

Pienso que es por alguna falla en el pool de conexiones pero no encuentro mucha información o una conexión que me sirva

Comment: Cuando intento acceder al sitio me aparece lo siguiente en consola: `ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.7.0.xml::1.7.0::bburke@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, en resumen me base en la documentación oficial para poder solucionar este problema de conexión, consulte los siguientes links :

Para la instalación de keycloak fue a través de este sitio: https://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html y descargue la ultima versión (11.0.2)

Es necesario descargar los drivers de MySQL y generar un modulo, además de otras modificaciones que pueden ser consultadas en la siguiente página oficial: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#unicode-considerations-for-database, aunque el ejemplo se basa mayormente en PostgresSql me apoye de la siguiente página para saber como nombrar los tags en XML con MySQL: https://www.tutorialsbuddy.com/keycloak-mysql-setup, la página explica la posibilidad de encontrarse con errores la primera vez que se inicia el sistema en conjunto con MySQL y te dice como corregirlo, además de todo esto corregí la conexión a BD (esto por la zona horaria) que resuelta quedaría algo así :

`<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>`

Talvez este proceso no sea muy claro, pero no puedo explicar todo paso a paso por que conlleva mucha información por detrás, recomiendo leer los links proporcionados y obtendrán el resultado deseado, claro si algún día hacen uso de esas tecnologías